# Why isn't the wpcf7submit event working in Contact Form 7 with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, dom-events, contact-form-7

I'm trying to capture the wpcf7submit event from a Contact Form 7 form on my WordPress site to trigger an alert when the form is successfully submitted. However, the event doesn't seem to trigger the function I've attached to it. Here's the code snippet I'm using within a script tag in my footer.php file, after the body content:

```
<div class="contact-form">
  <h2 class="contact-form__title">Contact</h2>
  <?php echo apply_shortcodes('[contact-form-7 id="fbe8376" title="Contact Form 1"]'); ?>
</div>
```

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  const wpcf7Elm = document.querySelector('.wpcf7');
  console.log(wpcf7Elm); // For debugging: to verify that the element is being selected.
  wpcf7Elm.addEventListener('wpcf7submit', function(event) {
    alert("Fire!");
  }, false);
});
```

I've confirmed that the .wpcf7 element exists in the DOM by checking the console output, which correctly logs the element. This indicates that the script correctly waits for the DOM to be fully loaded before attempting to attach the event listener.

Despite this, the alert doesn't appear when the form is submitted. I've checked for JavaScript errors in the console but haven't found any that seem related. The form itself works fine and submits as expected.

I'm wondering if there are any known issues with capturing wpcf7submit events like this, or if there's something wrong with how I'm trying to attach the event listener. Could there be a conflict with another script, or does Contact Form 7 require a different approach to capture submission events?

Comment: What happers if you add the event listener to the document instead:  document.addEventListener('wpcf7submit', function(event) {

Comment: Why are you wrapping the event listener is a `DOMContentLoaded` wrapper? It's not necessary.

Comment: @HowardE Wouldn't it be necessary if this code is in the <head>, or otherwise above where the form is inserted in the page?  Not necessary in the footer or below?  Either way, it wouldn't hurt anything, would it, or explain why the event listener isn't firing?

Comment: @ChadPhillips Have you read the docs on the contact form 7 website for usage of the dom events?  It explains how to use them.

Comment: @HowardE Yes, and I've been using this hook for years.  Note that in this code, Khang is attaching the event listener to the .wpcf7 element (I personally always attach it to the document).  If this code appears before that element exists, it will fail, which is why they are using DOMContentLoaded.